# Replacing the Graphics Card on a Laptop

Tags: laptop, intel-graphics

So, I want to replace my graphics card. The graphics card I have is an Intel 3000, and the minimum requirement for the software I want to run is an Intel 4000. Is that possible on a laptop? Also, if this helps, I have an Intel Core i5 processor and 4GB of RAM. One more thing; I have an HP Elitebook 8460p, which is a business laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't. *typically* intel graphics is on the processor die (or on older systems the chipset). As such replacing intel integrated graphics means replacing the processor, and typically these are restricted by what the bios supports (which is a whole different question), or simply soldered in place.

You might be able to pick up a fairly low cost expresscard or mini pci-e adaptor that will allow you to use a desktop class card on an older machine, which might be a more workable solution. [Google](https://www.google.com.sg/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=expressport%20pcie%20video%20adaptor) would be your friend for specific options, though apparently the 'gdc beast' is the common brand/model that seems to be floating around. Pair this up with a cheapish nvidia or amd card and this would be a simple option that won't void your warranty.